# VB.Net Secure Passwords to Database?

Tags: database, vb.net, encryption

I recently made a small app for a friend and then made it a public app, in doing so I forgot that it connects to my MS SQL DB and checks for values. Someone used Red Gate .Net Reflector to get my password and destroy it all. I've contacted their ISP and they are looking into it, apparently this person has a static ip with them.

So this is a lesson learned at a heavy price for me. How can I prevent this from happening again? How can I get away from the unsafe connection string they were able to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never hard code connection strings. Use the configuration section provided for it ([`connectionStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx)), and if really paranoid, [encrypt it](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Encrypting-Connection-String.aspx).

If you are using a shared database, you should not even have a connection string on the client, but create a service point (for example a webservice) that will connect to the database on their behalf. The client can connect to this and your connection string is safe behind your service, which is in your control and on your server.

Answer (score 2):

Don't expose a database connection, but have your app communicate through a webservice, or similar, that only has methods and privileges, to do what the app needs.

If you absolutely need the database connection, make sure the user only has read permissions on the database.

Encrypting the connection string is a start, but your program will have to know how to decrypt it for it to be useful. If your program can decrypt it, an attacker will also be able to - you can only affect the amount of work he needs to put in it.

Therefore, in my opinion, you should expose a read-only service.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a public app, you need to provide individual logins for each user or have a proxy sitting between the database and the application which authenticates the users and talks to the database.

Encrypting the connection string wouldn't help much, I think it can be easily decrypted with built-in tools or with Crack.net.

Answer (score 1):

If you're suuuper paranoid, prompt the sysadmin for the password each time the application starts (maybe an admin interface.)  That way it's only memory resident.

I love this question.  Like driis said, even with encrypted connection strings you need to store a password (or key, or whatever) to decrypt your encrypted connection string.  Just more layers of the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using connection strings and encrypted sections in you config will won't stop this type of attack, it's only designed to make the config file unreadable on a machine other than which it is installed.

The only safe way is to create a web service that connects to your database to retrieve the data, and then make sure that the web service logon only has the minimum permissons required, or force the user of the web service to logon and them impersonate that user for the database connection.

It appears you don't have firewall protection to stop external connections directly to your database so I wonder what other even more dangerous ports you may have exposed to the internet???

Using a firewall to limit access to your server to http, and https protocols would reduce the chances of a successful attack.